# How to add spring views dynamically

Tags: vaadin

I would like add spring views conditionally.
Couldnt find a way to do this. 
Can someone pls help me with it.

Ex - i have 2 views as below , based on the logged user , i would 
like to show only 1 of them and the other shall not be available even through url like http://localhost:7071/#!view2

```
@SpringView(name = "view1")
public class View1 extends VerticalLayout { ... }

@SpringView(name = "view2")
public class View2 extends VerticalLayout { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use security control like this:

```
import org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation.RequiresRoles;

@SpringView(name = "view1")
@RequiresRoles(value = "ROLE1")
public class View1 extends VerticalLayout { ... }

@SpringView(name = "view2")
@RequiresRoles(value = "ROLE2")
public class View2 extends VerticalLayout { ... }
```